# Constraint change is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a view & its Constraint is as per following.

[image]

now, when I am changing to constaint as per follow:

```
     [cell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.view_label 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
    toItem:cell.view_label.superview 
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:60]];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                [cell.view_label updateConstraints];
                [cell.view_label.superview updateConstraints];
            }];
```

**//Not Working**

Wraning:

> Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you
>   don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The
>   methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
>   listed in  may also be helpful.

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Change the priority of your constraint, The priority of 1000 makes this a required constraint.

Comment: @tdelepine, thanks for your answer! but I already tried with all priorities.

Comment: @user2893370 Add an outlet to the constraint in IB and change its constant value in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Since you have already a constraint in IB, update that in code. You don't need to add a constraint for the same purpose. Connect an `IBOutlet` to that constraint and modify its `constant` value in code.

Comment: I accpted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a *new* constraint there. The old constraint is still in place, and it can't satisfy both, hence the warning.

You need to modify the `constant` property of the existing constraint. The best way to do this is to make an outlet to it.